# FloatingActionButton not showing properly on pre-L devices

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I've implemented a layout which is having a cover image and layout below are ImageView and Textview. In the center of these two views I have FloatingActionButton. See those two dark green icons, those are my FAB's. Yes,  those two icons are not being displayed properly on Kitkat device. How to set this properly on pre-L devices?

But on Lollipop devices and above it's working fine for the FAB's and it shows properly

layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <com.test.example.view.ObservableParallaxScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="268dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="104.9dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image_cover"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

           <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/icon1"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cover"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="145dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/icon2"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cover"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon2"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cover"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="21dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp">

              <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image2"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="146dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
              </LinearLayout

              <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                  <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

              </LinearLayout

       </LinearLayout
    </RelativeLayout
    </com.test.example.view.ObservableParallaxScrollView>
```

This is the output I'm getting on pre-Lollipop devices
(Kitkat Device, JB)
[image: Image output Result]

This is the output on Lollipop devices and above and what I'm after

[image: Lollipop devices and above]

```
    dependencies {
          compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    }
```

Comment: The comparison image is helpful. The problem is your FABs aren't floating, they are clipped to the boundary of the view that contains them. I think the FABs need to be contained in a CoordinatorLayout so that they can be drawn above the other views.